# Iterate table <tr> using JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I want to iterate table  using JSON data. My JS function return `result` JSON. I want to print its values in `tr`. I have mentioned the code below.

Tried Table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {{#each result}}
       <tr>
          <td>{{this.currency_name}}</td>
          <td>{{this.rate}}</td>
       </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But my above-tried code not work. It did not print anything. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: what is template u are using ?? {{#each result}}

Comment: I am using handlebars. here  `result' and `table` is in the same handlebar page

Comment: can you show us a piece of code responsible for rendering the template?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Actually I have created a `result` array successfully. I want to know how can use that data in `result` to show in the table.

Comment: how is your server setup? how are you returning the template to the user? you've provided no code even showing an attempt at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code below is what you're looking for. I'm using `foreach` loop to your array object holder which's `result`. I hope this will help you. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<table id="table_id">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
    $('#table_id tbody tr').remove();

    result.forEach(
           item => insert_items(item.currency_name,item.rate)
    );

    function insert_items(currency_name,rate){

             var summary_table = '<tr id="">'+     
                                      '<td>'+currency_name+'</td>'+                          
                                      '<td>'+rate+'</td>'+
                                  '</tr>';

             $("#table_id tbody").prepend(summary_table);

    }
```

Comment: @Jesper Martinez I want to solve one thing on your answer. This `result` applies in the edit model for each product in my system . there are a lot of products. When I click one product and again click another product previous data also applies in that product. always `result` should be empty when beginning. How can it resolve?

Comment: Okay. first is you need to remove your previous Table data. like this `$('#table_id tbody tr').remove();` you can insert it before to your `function insert_items(){}`....

Comment: or before to your `result.forEach()`